# how to move styling from HTML to CSS?

Tags: html, css

how do i move all my styling in html to css? When i copy and paste it, it's not working properly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">



<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        table,
        td,
        th {
            border-bottom: 1px solid #c4dcf3;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            padding: 5px;
        }
        
        tfoot {
            text-align: left;
        }
        
        tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
            background-color: #eef7ff;
        }
    </style>


</head>

<body>
    <table>
        <thead style="background-color: #427fef;">
            <tr>
                <th>Country</th>
                <th>OrderID</th>
                <th>Order Amount</th>
            </tr>

        </thead>

        <tbody>

            <tr>
                <td>USA</td>
                <td>1000</td>
                <td>$1,300</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>USA</td>
                <td>1001</td>
                <td>$700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>CA</td>
                <td>1002</td>
                <td>$2,000</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>CA</td>
                <td>1003</td>
                <td>$1,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

        <tfoot>
            <tr style="background-color: #427fef;">
                <th>Total</th>
                <th align="center" colspan="2">$5,000</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>




</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please don't fill the question up with junk text for it to be accepted - add meaningful content instead.

Comment: what exactly did you try? everything that is between the `<style>` tags should be moved into a fill ending with `.css`. Then a reference to the css needs to be linked in the head element. https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp

Comment: Hi! You need to define "not working properly" term. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for best ways to ask questions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
i just link .css file within header

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">



<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyles.css">
    <title>Document</title>
   


</head>

<body>
    <table>
        <thead style="background-color: #427fef;">
            <tr>
                <th>Country</th>
                <th>OrderID</th>
                <th>Order Amount</th>
            </tr>

        </thead>

        <tbody>

            <tr>
                <td>USA</td>
                <td>1000</td>
                <td>$1,300</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>USA</td>
                <td>1001</td>
                <td>$700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>CA</td>
                <td>1002</td>
                <td>$2,000</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>CA</td>
                <td>1003</td>
                <td>$1,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

        <tfoot>
            <tr style="background-color: #427fef;">
                <th>Total</th>
                <th align="center" colspan="2">$5,000</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>




</body>

</html>



and your mystyles.css is like 

 table,
        td,
        th {
            border-bottom: 1px solid #c4dcf3;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            padding: 5px;
        }
        
        tfoot {
            text-align: left;
        }
        
        tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
            background-color: #eef7ff;
        }
```